# C# SQL connection timeout

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, timeout

I have a very strange case of SQL connection timeout from an application written in C# .NET.

The `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is being used to sequentially execute several scripts in SQL Server, one after another. Each script contains a command to create just one table (no data update/insert/delete operations at all). For some reason, at one of the scripts, the `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` throws a timeout exception.

When I execute creation of all these tables in SQL Server Management Studio, they get executed just fine and almost instantaneously.

Does anyone has an idea what could be causing timeout when the tables are created from the application?

All sql scripts look similar like following:

SQL:

```
create table dbo.Test  
(  
  Code varchar(10) not null  
, Name varchar(50) not null  
, other columns...  

  primary key  
, unique key  
, foreign key
)
```

The scripts are shipped from C# using this code:

```
try
{
  using (SqlConnection conSQL = new SqlConnection ("[connection string]"))
  {
     using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conSQL))
     {
       cmdSQL.CommandTimeout = iTimeOut;
       conSQL.Open();

       cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is where it jumps to catch part and                                                                            
                                 // throws out timeout exception
       conSQL.Close();
     }
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw (ex);
}
```

This is happening on the Test server, meaning nothing else is happening on the server while the application is executing these scripts.

Comment: we need to see your relevant c# code and sql query.

Comment: try `cmdSQL.CommandTimeout = 0;`

Comment: Would you agree that the sql script is very simple right? I just don't understand why this one script is timing out and the rest don't. To note, nothing else is running on the Test sql server, the iTimeOut value is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default time out setting for sql transactions by updating the `machine.config`, which can be found here:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config
```

64-bit

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```

At the end of the `machine.config` add or update the following line:

```
<system.transactions>
   <machineSettings maxTimeout="01:00:00" />  --> set this to desired value.
 </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

If the above doesn't work, you can specify the `Timeout setting` for `SqlCommand` through code as well:

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
     connection.Open();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
     // Setting command timeout in seconds:
     command.CommandTimeout = 3600;
     try {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (SqlException e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
     }
  }
```

more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have raised the timeout till 1 minute, no help. Setting to a higher value is not good in my opinion. I am trying to find out the reason why this is happening

Comment: I believe the default is 10 minutes? so not sure why you think more than 1 minute is bad. However show us the code of the script that is causing it, maybe we can see what's happening that way?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the relevant c# code (Where you are calling these sql queries) and an example query?

Comment: I just wanted to say that it is a very simple script that executes under 1 second in management studio. Giving it to execute in 1 minute or more is kinda too much. There should be another option other than that...

Comment: what's the value of your iTimeout? if it's too low, it will cause a timeout error.

Comment: it is 30 seconds, should be enough

Comment: @Andy, you need to measure if it's enough. Try increasing it and see if that fixes the problem. There could be other things at play here

Answer (score 0):

Just stop it from running and run again your problem will be solved.... It is generally occur first time only when their are lot of files to load maybe it is bug in visual studio.
New:
After stop try to refresh open Web page (in browser where error displays ) instead of relaunch it again...

Comment: I have done this several times, the problems occurs at each relaunch of the application.